# Alfresco - status for tasks and calendar

Tags: calendar, task, alfresco, status, alfresco-share

how to define more status for task in Alfresco 5.2, 
for example how to between the status 'Not Yet startded' and status 'In progress' add new status 'NEW STATUS'.

```
'Not Yet startded'
**'NEW STATUS'**
'In progress'
```

Is there any way to show in calendar date all of the created task?

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1):

All the statuses are defined in the bpmModel.xml file.

```
<constraint name="bpm:allowedStatus" type="LIST">
     <parameter name="allowedValues">
        <list>
            <value>Not Yet Started</value>
            <value>In Progress</value>
            <value>On Hold</value>
            <value>Cancelled</value>
            <value>Completed</value>
        </list>
    </parameter>
</constraint>


            <!--  Task Progress -->
            <property name="bpm:status">
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                <default>Not Yet Started</default>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint ref="bpm:allowedStatus" />
                </constraints>
            </property>
```

But it is not recommened to edit the default alfresco resources.

Comment: think that you have to make your last comment (But it is not ...) between ** because i think that alfresco is set to default every 3 days this is whi it's pointless to change something alfresco set to default

Comment: How to find bpmModel.xml??? I use alfresco share, i try to find but without success...

Comment: It will be present in alfresco(repository side) and not in Share side.

Comment: Is there any way to add new status in Alfresco Share? I am new in Alfresco and I install alfresco 5.2. I try to find way to add status but without success,Do you have any suggestions or advice....

Comment: Can you give me a path to bpmModel.xm, and what is repository side how to find that?